# How to validate multiple urls separated by commas using a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I need to validate multiple url's seperated by commas using a regular expression. 
Condition:-

1. It should also disallow the usage of the prefixes such as ***'http://',*** '***www.***', **'https://'**.

2.It should also disallow suffixes which are less than two characters.

> My valid url strings are :-
>   google.com,test.us,list.net
>
> My invalid url strings are:-
>   www.yahoo.com,http(s)://www.google.in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead at the start to set the condition of not allowing `http://` or `https://` or `www.` substrings inside that.

```
^(?!.*\b(?:https?:\/\/|www\.))\w+(?:\.\w+)*\.\w{2,}(?:,\w+(?:\.\w+)*\.\w{2,})+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/32)

Use this if you want to allow exactly one dot in each url.

```
^(?!.*\b(?:https?:\/\/|www\.))\w+\.\w{2,}(?:,\w+\.\w{2,})+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/33)

Comment: Hey there is another issue with your expression. But if i give just a single url instead of multiple url's , it fails. I only found out now.

Comment: Simple. Just turn the last plus symbol to star.

Comment: just cross check your expression with this link : 
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page